# Visual Studio publish install fail

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, publish

I have a project which has a multi-level dir of templates used by the app.

I include these files thus:

```
<Content Include="..\Content\**\*.*">
  <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

The resulting publish looks correct but the install fails on a dir/file combination which has C# in the name. The error in the install log is:

```
    + Downloading file:///Z:/Deploy/Application Files/MyApp_1_0_0_1/Template/Shared Code C%23/Shared Code C%23.csproj did not succeed.
    + Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\Deploy\Application Files\MyApp_1_0_0_1\Template\Shared Code C%23\Shared Code C%23.csproj'.
```

I basically want the contents of my Content folder (but not the folder Content itself) installed in the same directory as the rest of the app.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that statement :-)

Comment: Maybe...I've seen plenty of Visual Studio questions asked/answered. It seems to me this shouldn't be a difficult problem for someone experienced in publishing a project.

Comment: I suspect Visual Studio comes under:

* software tools commonly used by programmers

Comment: Yes, you might be right regarding this.